# Administrator, superuser or root privileges?

Tags: discussion

In [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49387/is-there-mono-appindicator-notification-area-icon-available-for-xchat/49423#49423) that I helped in reformatting, you can see reference to privilege gained by using `sudo`, `gksu`, etc are referred to by administrator privileges (by me) and superuser privileges (by author). What is the proper reference to the privileges?

IMO, I don't think it should be root privileges because, even using `sudo`, there are some restrictions. And superuser sounds improper and does not give a real meaning, being one of the terms .

Please share your opinion on the matter.

Answer (score 4):

*Superuser* is the proper term.

When talking about Linux systems, *Administrator* often means a normal user that may gain superuser privileges via `su` or `sudo` (super user *do*). You can also call it *root privileges* if you want to be entirely unambiguous, as sudo give the admin 'privileges like root'.

Comment: `su` stands for `Switch User`, whereas `sudo` stands for `Switch User & Do` it just so happens that the default user to switch to is `0` You can `sudo` as a user other than root with `sudo -u [uid] [command]`

Comment: You mean id `0` (the `root` account). If `[uid]` is a number, you need to prefix it with a dash. Should the command start with a `-`, you'd better put `--` before it to make sure that sudo it not interpreting it as an option (useful for user-supplied commands). Example: `sudo -u#1001 -- whoami` (with no whitespace between `-u` and `#`)

Comment: Where did you learn about "switch user"? I find _many_ different opinions as to the 'official' acronym (of the old "su" that is) on the internets. My source is a Unix book from the early nineties

Comment: The man page. Both are correct - I don't think there is a set Acronym for su/sudo.

Answer (score 0):

The privileges gained with `su` or `sudo` are called properly called root privileges. That's the definition of what these commands do, in fact: execute a command as root.

Superuser is an informal synonym of root user. Administrator generally refers to a physical user who is legitimately able to gain root privileges.